# How to implement glMultMatrixf

Tags: c, opengl

I am working on a Matrix product function and I am new to C. This is what I came up with...

```
static float *currentMatrix;
...
glMultMatrixf(const float *m){
  int i;
  int i2=0;
  int i3=0;
  float result[16]={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
  printf("starting \n");
  for(i=0; i < (MATRIX_HEIGHT); i++){
    float dotProduct = 0.0f;
    for(i2=0; i2 < (MATRIX_WIDTH); i2++){
      float dotProduct = 0.0f;
      for(i3=0;i3 < (MATRIX_WIDTH); i3++){
        dotProduct+=currentMatrix[i3+i*4]*m[i3*4+i2];
      }
      result[i2+i*4]=dotProduct;
    }
  }
  currentMatrix = &result[0];
  printf("Finished \n");
}
```

Of course this fails because of the scope of result.

This does work...

```
static float *currentMatrix;
float result[16]={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
...
glMultMatrixf(const float *m){
  int i;
  int i2=0;
  int i3=0;

  printf("starting \n");
  for(i=0; i < (MATRIX_HEIGHT); i++){
    float dotProduct = 0.0f;
    for(i2=0; i2 < (MATRIX_WIDTH); i2++){
      float dotProduct = 0.0f;
      for(i3=0;i3 < (MATRIX_WIDTH); i3++){
        dotProduct+=currentMatrix[i3+i*4]*m[i3*4+i2];
      }
      result[i2+i*4]=dotProduct;
    }
  }
  currentMatrix = &result[0];
  printf("Finished \n");
}
```

But this doesn't seem right because if multiple threads are calling the function at the same time seems like this would cause issues (remember I am new to C).

So I don't really know the right way of preventing the GC from destroying those objects. I of course could iterate through the temp array and set the value in the regular array but that seems inefficient. Is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: C doesn't have automatic GC.

Comment: A function like this can't be used in multi-threaded code, unless the callers do their own mutual exclusion. This is why many standard library functions have two forms: `XXX` and `XXX_r()` -- the latter is a re-entrant version with a different signature so it doesn't use static variables.

Comment: Don't use static data - it's false economy. Use the signature: `(float *, const float *, const float *)`, even if the result may alias one of the sources - write the result back from a local `float [16]` temp. If it matters that much, there are plenty of highly optimized GL maths libs around.

Comment: +Brett Hale I would be very interested in links to these GL libs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an implementation: `[R] <- [A][B]` => `matrix4_mul(r, a, b);`
Simple ISO C90. the result: `(r)` may alias `(x)` and/or `(y)`. It hasn't been tested:

```
/* inline */ void
matrix4_mul (float r[16], const float a[16], const float b[16])
{
    float t[16]; /* (tmp result) */
    int i, j, k;

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        const float *ai = a + (i * 4);
        float *ti = t + (i * 4);

        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            float tij = 0.0;

            for (k = 0; k < 4; k++)
                tij += ai[k] * b[k * 4 + j];

            ti[j] = tij; /* r[i][j] (inner product) */
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 16; i++) /* copy elements back to result: */
        r[i] = t[i];
}
```

Any row-major vs. col-major issues just depend on the ordering of `[A]` and `[B]`.

---

If you want to mimic the behavior of `glMultMatrixf`, you need to maintain the notion of a current matrix / matrix stack. At least this function can do the actual concatenation.

Comment: Check out my response and see how you think it compares, essentially I did the same only used memcpy

Comment: @Jackie - `memcpy` is basically a waste of time for 16 single precision floats - 64 bytes. The call overhead probably costs more than the loop. This way, the compiler can shuffle operations around, and optimize the lot - it might unroll the loops entirely. Take out the `printf` calls, and code generated for your function would likely be nearly identical to mine if using an optimizing compiler.

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to implement the OpenGL routine `glMultMatrix`. There is no choice about how to return the result. OpenGL has some concept of a “current matrix”. I am not familiar with OpenGL. I presume the current matrix is part of some global or thread-specific state, because it is not passed to `glMultMatrix` as a parameter. To implement `glMultMatrix`, you must also implement OpenGL’s global state. It appears you will have to learn something about OpenGL.

Given that `glMultMatrix` must both read from the current matrix and write to it, and the operation cannot be performed in place (except by using numerous temporary variables), then you have two choices:

- Produce the results in a temporary matrix, then copy the temporary matrix to the current matrix. Or, equivalently, copy the current matrix to a temporary matrix, then use the temporary matrix for input while producing results in the current matrix.
- Maintain the current matrix as a pointer to two or more actual matrices. In a routine such as `glMultMatrix`, read from the currently pointed-to version of the current matrix and write to the other version of the matrix. At the end of the routine, change the pointer to point to the new results.

The latter option is relatively simple and does not consume an excessive amount of space, since the current matrix is small. Variations are possible, such as normally keeping only one current matrix but allocating space for others as necessary, and using a pointer to indicate which one is the real current matrix.

Comment: Unfortunately this is a port so changing the parameters is a not an option. The second one I could see working but it seems like the copying of the array is safer (what if I forget to free). If there is a way to copy array values without (explicitly) iterating that would be ideal.

Comment: I'll look into it again new at C so I didn't think of that

Comment: This is a port in which you are allowed to change the implementation of `glMultMatrixf` but not its declaration? How does the previous implementation return results? What is the declaration (does it return a value)?

Comment: @EricPostpischil very valid remark - by the looks of it via shared variables, making it very perilous to retrofit threading to that proogram...

Comment: @EricPostpischil I am not sure, I am not sure where to find the implementation code for OpenGL ES1.1 I would assume it depends on the driver implementation. Again I am new to all this

Answer (score 0):

Looks like +FVU was right, memcpy seems to work...

```
glMultMatrixf(const float *m){
  int i;
  int i2=0;
  int i3=0;
  printf("starting \n");
  float result[16]={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
  for(i=0; i < (MATRIX_HEIGHT); i++){
   float dotProduct = 0.0f;
   for(i2=0; i2 < (MATRIX_WIDTH); i2++){
     float dotProduct = 0.0f;
     for(i3=0;i3 < (MATRIX_WIDTH); i3++){
       printf("Multiplying... currentLoc %d New M Loc %d | %f * %f", i3+i*4, i3*4+i2, currentMatrix[i3+i*4],m[i3*4+i2]);
       dotProduct+=currentMatrix[i3+i*4]*m[i3*4+i2];
       printf(" Dot Product = %f \n", dotProduct);
     }
     result[i2+i*4]=dotProduct;
   }
  }

  memcpy(currentMatrix, &result, 16 * sizeof(float) );
  printf("Finished \n");
}
```